# SMTP for multiple domains on virtual interfaces

Tags: linux, email, smtp, email-server, sendmail

The setup is like this (Ubuntu 9.10):

> eth0: 1.1.1.1 name.isp.com
>
> eth0:0 2.2.2.2 example2.com
>
> eth0:1 3.3.3.3 example3.com

`example2.com` and `example3.com` are web apps which need to send emails to their users.

`2.2.2.2` points to `example2.com` and vice-versa (A/PTR). MX -> Google. Google handles all incoming mail.

`3.3.3.3` points to `example3.com` and vice-versa (A/PTR). MX -> Google. Google handles all incoming mail.

Requirements:

1. Local delivery must be disabled (must deliver to MX specified server), so that the following works (note that there is no local user `bob` on the machine, but there is an existing bob email user):

   `echo "Test" | mail -s "Test 6" bob@example2.com`
2. I need to be able to specify from which IP/domain name the email is delivered when sending an email.

I fought with sendmail. With not much luck.

Here's some debug info:

```
sendmail -d0.12 -bt < /dev/null

Canonical name: name.isp.com
UUCP nodename: host
    a.k.a.: example2.com
    a.k.a.: example3.com
    ...
```

Sendmail always uses canonical name (taken from eth0). I've found no way for it to select one of the UUCP codenames. It uses it for sending email:

```
echo -e "To: test@example2.com\nSubject: Test\nTest\n" | sendmail -bm -t -v

test@example2.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 name.isp.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9ubuntu1; Wed, 31 Mar 2010 16:33:55 +0200; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO name.isp.com
```

I'm ok with other SMTP solutions. I've looked briefly at nbsmtp, msmtp and nullmailer but I'm not sure they can deal with disabling local delivery and selecting different domains when sending emails.

I also know about spoofing sender field by using `mail -a "From: <bob@example2.com>"` but it seems to be a half-solution (mails are still sent from isp.com domain instead of proper example2.com, so PTR records are unused and there's more risk of being flagged as spam/spammer).

Comment: Hi Paweł,

I have the same problem as yours. 
Did you succeeded to solve it with sendmail? 
Can you post your solution? It would help me a lot.

Thanks,
Levi

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about `sendmail`, but with `exim` you specify routers and transports. Routers take the email from/to addresses and decide which transport to use. For (1), Just create smtp transports and no local transports. For (2), you can specify an `interface` option when you create a transport. A config file would be something like this (not a complete config file and not tested):

```
begin routers

example2_route:
 driver = dnslookup
 condition = ${eq{$sender_address_domain}{example2.com}} # 'from' domain is example2.com
 transport = example2_smtp

example3_route:
 driver = dnslookup
 condition = ${eq{$sender_address_domain}{example3.com}}
 transport = example3_smtp

begin transports

example2_smtp:
 driver = smtp
 interface = 2.2.2.2

example3_smtp:
 driver = smtp
 interface = 3.3.3.3
```

Comment: Seems to be what I want. So far I've assembled a semi-decent sendmail setup. I'll give it a try in the nearest future.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [mailertable](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/mailertables.html)? Mapping

```
do.main    esmtp:do.main
```

should work and make sendmail use the MX-record (untested).

Answer (score 0):

I have setup multiple postfix instances in the manner you describe to service outgoing mail for two namespaces. It is a fairly involved procedure (mine more so since I am also DKIMProxy signing) but a good starting point is: http://advosys.ca/papers/email/58-postfix-instance.html

I documented the whole thing (on RHEL 5.6) so I can provide more detail, so let me know if you're going this route - I can provide additional info.

The Exim approach posted by Dan looks cleaner - I stuck with postfix/DKIMProxy since I've used this approach in the past.

Cheers