# Sendmail : forwarding emails problem

Tags: sendmail, forwarding

So here is my situation.
I have this 2 DNS (say a.org and b.org) with the same IP address (both A record) tied to this box. We have Google mail handing our a.org emails . I want b.org emails to forward to users at a.org emails . My sendmail is getting confused and is delivering all b.org emails locally instead of forwarding them to a.org (which is specified in the .forward) .
What do I do from the sendmail side to force external delivery .
Thanks Much

Comment: You're seeing another instance of [SMTP for multiple domains on virtual interfaces](http://serverfault.com/questions/128163/smtp-for-multiple-domains-on-virtual-interfaces/230297#230297).

Answer (score 2):

- add "FEATURE(`mailertable')" to sendmail.mc
- run m4(make) to install new config, then restart sendmail
- add to /etc/mail/mailertable ".b.org     smtp:[aspmx.l.google.com]"
- makemap hash /etc/mail/mailertable < /etc/mail/mailertable
- test